# What does it mean for the JSON interchange format to have a license?

Tags: licensing, legal, json

A recent flurry of comments on a [JSHint issue](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1234) alerted me to the fact that the JSON data-interchange format has a [license](http://www.json.org/license.html).

The content of this license can be debated elsewhere.

What I'm unclear on is what it means for JSON (or any other data-interchance format) to have a license.

If an a library simply consumes and parses JSON, does it have to include this license? I understand that using a library that contains this license would require a user to include it. I'm talking about writing a library from scratch.

What if I have to use JSON because a third party service only communicates via JSON. If I'm serializing and deserializing data according to the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627), do I still need to refer to the license?

Comment: The license also applies to the documentation.  I think referring to 'software' is mostly just a legal CYA.

Comment: Yeah... it just occurred to me that the license refers to documentation and software. Since JSON is neither, does this license make *any* sense?

Comment: I wonder what "software" the license is referring to, because JSON is a standard for a data-interchange format, not executable software.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that the license refers to the [*reference implementation of JSON*](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java), not to the JSON format itself.

As an aside, I find it amusing that people get so worked up over the "not evil" clause.  See [this Douglas Crockford video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-C-JoyNuQJs#t=39m47s) for some perspective.

Comment: +1 for noting the reference aspect.  As to the "not evil" clause, Crockford is geeky enough to understand that he created this problem, not everyone else (OK, Stallman created it, but that's the more-general case).